# Is it possible to complete this in one SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables in a SQLite DB file.  In case you're not familiar, as I wasn't, it's able to handle most SQL SELECT statements, but it's not full blown enterprise capable, in case that affects your strategy here.

I feel like I know this is doable, but it's been so long since I wrote a semi-complex SELECT statement. I can't figure it out, so I thought I'd turn to the pros here.

The 3 tables contain student gradebook data.  I'm trying to do a simple aggregation of student demographics.  I'd like to ultimately have a query return these results.

| Class | # Students | Percent | GPA | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Period 1 | 37 | 84.1 | 3.11 | 18 | 11 |
| Period 2 | 32 | 78.4 | 3.01 | 16 | 15 |
| Period 3 | 34 | 88.0 | 2.37 | 14 | 13 |

Tables are as follows (I've removed irrelevant fields here).  In SQLite, text is similar to varchar(255) and real is basically a float.  I realize that it seems like some of these fields should be integers, but that's a separate external issue that we don't need to address here.

```
Table: Gradebook
gradebook_number, text     
period, text
```

```
Table: rosters
gradebook_number, text
perm_id, text       # this is the student id number
percent, real
```

```
Table: students
perm_id, text
gender, text
gpa, real
```

Figuring out the number of students, the average percent and the avg gpa isn't a problem.  But I don't know how to count the number of male and females.  Here is my statement so far.

```
SELECT g.period, count(s.perm_id) as num_students, round(avg(r.percent),2) as percent,
      round(avg(s.gpa),2) as school_gpa
  FROM rosters r, students s, gradebooks g
  WHERE r.perm_id = s.perm_id AND r.gradebook_number = g.gradebook_number
  GROUP BY g.period
  ORDER BY g.period
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use conditional aggregation and definitely use the current SQL standard of explicit joins of `INNER JOIN...ON` (not the older implicit joins with `WHERE` clauses).

```sql
SELECT 
    g.period, 
    count(s.perm_id) as num_students, 
    round(avg(r.percent),2) as percent,
    round(avg(s.gpa),2) as school_gpa,
    sum(s.gender = 'Male') as male_students,
    sum(s.gender = 'Female') as female_students
 
FROM rosters r
INNER JOIN students s
  ON r.perm_id = s.perm_id
INNER JOIN gradebooks g
  ON r.gradebook_number = g.gradebook_number
GROUP BY g.period
ORDER BY g.period
```

Comment: I figured I was over thinking it.  Thanks.  I definitely learned something here.  I'll also up my understanding of the INNER and OUTER joins.  I didn't know the other method was considered an old method.  Aging myself here I guess.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` statement to count (using `sum`) make and female individually:

```
SELECT
  g.period,
  count(s.perm_id) as num_students,
  round(avg(r.percent),2) as percent,
  round(avg(s.gpa),2) as school_gpa,
  sum(case when s.gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male,
  sum(case when s.gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as female
FROM rosters r, students s, gradebooks g
WHERE r.perm_id = s.perm_id AND r.gradebook_number = g.gradebook_number
GROUP BY g.period
ORDER BY g.period
```